# C# - Reading XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read an XML file in order to integrate data into Windows Phone App.

I followed some other topics but I cannot get it to work (I feel I'm almost at the point but still missing something).

The XML I'm trying to read is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
    <item value="0">status</item>
    <item value="210">online</item>
    <item value="22h 49m 49s">uptime</item>
    <item value="90">latency</item>
    <item value="423">maxplayers_ever</item>
    <item value="263">maxplayers_week</item>
    <item value="252">maxplayers</item>
</items>
```

It contains information for a game server.

I'm reading it from an URL, that's the code I use:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    private void LoadXMLFile()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.forgottenlands.eu/data.xml.php"));
    }

    private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "TEST I REACH HTTPS" });

            XDocument statusinfo = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

            List<Item> items =
                (from node in statusinfo.Elements("Item")
                 select new Item
                 {
                     Name = (string)node.Value,

                     Value = (string)node.Attribute("Value")

                 }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in items)
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = item.Name + " " + item.Value });

            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }   
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        // Sample data; replace with real data
        // the xml file contains your provided xml code

        LoadXMLFile();
    }
```

It seems like that I go correctly into the `httpscompleted` function, but I don't get correctly the XML data.

Comment: "i dont get correctly the XML data" doesn't give us any useful information. What *are* you seeing? Note that currently you're trying to fetch the `Item` element and the `Value` attribute - when they should be `item` and `value`. Is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems in your current code:

- You're asking the *document* for the `Item` elements, instead of the document root element
- You're asking for `Item` elements instead of `item` elements
- You're asking for the `Value` attribute instead of the `value` attribute

I'd also not use a query expression for this, as it's making things more complicated than they need to be:

```
var items = statusInfo.Root.Elements("item")
                      .Select(node => new Item {
                                 Name = (string) node,
                                 Value = (string) node.Attribute("value")
                              })
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, copy-pasted compiled and my app works perfect now.
Just one more question, you used the Root.Elements command with argument "item", this means that it will retrieve all the nodes with "item" or only the lowest level (child) elements? I would like to add another sublevel below <item>, and i will need to retrieve both this sublevel info and the item info... is it possible?

Comment: @user2677397: No, I used the `Root` property and then called the `Elements` method on the result. (There's no such thing as a "command" in C#, and it's important to understand how properties and methods work.) It will only retrieve immediate children - if you want *all* descendants, use the `Descendants` method instead of `Elements`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 XDocument DocumentObject = XDocument.Load("yourxml.xml");
 IEnumerable<XElement> Itrem = from ItemInfo in DocumentObject.Descendants("items").Elements("item") select ItemInfo;

        foreach (var t in Itrem)
        {
            string Item = (string)t.Value;
            string Itemvalue = (string)t.Attribute("value").Value;


        }
```